# Good blogs about multi-threaded development?

Tags: java, multithreading, testing, blogs

About a year ago I read the book "Java concurrency in practice" and I learned a lot from it.
I was wondering if there are any blogs about multi-threaded development in Java, since many topics discussed in blogs are not covered in books.

If this blog also contains techniques about testing thread-safety it would be great, but any blog about Java threads would be welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: Good question.  Too bad there aren't as many books as esteemed as the one you mention for other languages.  Concurrency is just moving to the importance category for many businesses instead of being front and central already.

Comment: check my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268087/recommended-book-about-parallel-programming-theory-best-practice/1509716#1509716 for a list of 15+ highly recommended books for threading and parallel programming

Answer (score 4):

[**Sutter’s Mill**](http://herbsutter.wordpress.com/) (Herb Sutter on software, hardware, and concurrency) is a blog with [**many posts about concurrency**](http://herbsutter.wordpress.com/category/concurrency/).

Comment: Mostly in terms of C++, but what goes there is usually relevant for other languages and platforms.

Answer (score 2):

- [Dave Dice](http://blogs.oracle.com/dave/) has some.
- [Carol McDonald](http://blogs.oracle.com/carolmcdonald/) has some, particularly with respect to JPA.
- [Václav Pech](http://www.jroller.com/vaclav/) has some (mostly Groovy related)
- [Alex Miller](http://puredanger.com/tech/index.php?cat=47&submit=view) has some (author of dzone refcard on [core java concurrency](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/core-java-concurrency))
- You could treat JSR 166 group's [concurrency interest mailing list](http://concurrency.markmail.org/) like a blog
- There are a number of JavaOne talks on concurrency with [PDFs available](http://developers.sun.com/learning/javaoneonline/j1online.jsp?track=javase&yr=2009) (ok - that's definately not a blog, but the amount of content made available each year might take a year to absorb.)
- [Microsoft Research CHESS](http://research.microsoft.com/CHESS/) team have a [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/chess/). (non-java, but multi-threaded testing)

Answer (score 1):

[Joe Duffy](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/Default.aspx) addresses concurrency and parallel programming a great deal in his archives.

He has a decidedly .Net spin, having been the PM for the Parallel extensions, but the principles he discusses are pretty universal.  You'll just need to translate to the appropriate Java APIs.  Only thing I can think of that might be fundamentally different is low level stuff that's dependent on acquire/release semantics of the underlying memory model.

Answer (score 1):

Just a few recommendations on top of what's already been discussed, in approximate descending order of usefulness (according to me, anyway):

- Alex Miller (as mentioned by spdenne) maintains [a concurrency link blog on tumblr](http://concurrency.tumblr.com/) which aggregates a lot of cool Java concurrency stuff
- [Cliff Click's blog](http://blogs.azulsystems.com/cliff/) -- an incredibly smart guy who works at Azul Systems, where they pretty much take Java concurrency to the extreme (we're talking machines with, like, a bajillion cores and a squillion gig of RAM)
- [Jeremy Manson's blog](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/) -- pretty much *the guy* (well, one of the guys) on Java memory model/concurrency/performance related issues (he was one of the authors of the new memory model)
- [Java Performance Tuning](http://www.javaperformancetuning.com/) -- combination of articles and links related to performance, often touches on concurrency stuff
- [Kirk Pepperdine](http://kirk.blog-city.com/), Java performance wiz -- more about general performance than concurrency specifically, but talks about concurrency sometimes (of course)
- [Java Specialist's Newsletter](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/archive.jsp) -- again, mostly performance, concurrency stuff sometimes